# Canvas LMS Install

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to install Canvas-LMS, but when installing yarn v1.10.1, I got this error:

```
[5/5] Building fresh packages ...
[1/15] ? node-sass
[6/15] ? uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
[7/15] ? spawn-sync
[8/15] ? fetch-mock
error / home / canvas / canvas-lms / node_modules / @ sentry / cli: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts / install.js
Arguments:
Directory: / home / canvas / canvas-lms / node_modules / @ sentry / cli
Output:
```

I do not understand what the problem is. Please help with this, I could not understand and it has been several days.

Comment: Are you following the Quick Start guide found on the wiki, (https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start#debianubuntu)?